# How to watch, compile. minify and join Coffescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have directory structure like this:

```
|-assets
|--...
|--coffee
|--js
|--...
```

I have Coffescript files in `/assets/coffe/` folder and I want to watch them for changes, compile, minify and concatenate into one single file `/assets/js/app.js`.

I've tried several commands from terminal, I even installed [coffeebar](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coffeebar) and ran some commands from there too, but I was not getting the result, what I was expecting.

I don't want to use Grunt, or Programs like Prepros and etc.

How to watch, compile, minify and join all coffeescript files into one js file from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`coffee -jwc ./assets/coffee/*.coffee`

http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html

Comment: Join (-j) has been deprecated